# How to discover length of notice period after mislaying contract

Tags: resignation, united-kingdom, notice-period

I've been employed as a web developer for around five years at a medium sized technology business in London. I'm thinking of leaving but I'm not quite sure what my notice period is.

Is there a good way to find out? I'm not sure where I put my copy of the contract five years ago. Obviously directly asking my manager or HR could affect my career if I don't leave soon. Is there any good way to get a new copy of my contract or otherwise find out what my notice period is?

Comment: In my experience, typical notice periods in the UK are from 4 weeks up to 3 months, depending on seniority. But ask for a copy of your contract.

Answer (score 9):

Do not ask about the notice period. Just inform HR that you have lost your copy of your contract and would like a replacement for your files.

Comment: "I sorted out lots of papers on the weekend and I couldn't find the contract. I do that once every year. " so there is no suspicion that there is a particular reason for checking the contract.

Comment: "*I do that once every year.*" That's about a clear a sign as you can give that you're lying about the real reason. A simple "I just noticed" is enough.

Comment: As @Lilienthal touches on - alter the truth as little as possible. You noticed you didn't have a copy of the contract, that's true, you've no reason to tell them why you noticed.

Comment: @gnasher729 Constructing a believable, consistent lie is hard. The truth is inherently consistent. If the OP sorted papers every year, the contract would have been missed at least four years ago, not this week. Or did the contract somehow evaporate from the OP's files after being in its proper place for three or four annual paper sorts?